# kernel takes long load time

Tags: boot, kernel, ssd, time

nearly I bought a ssd and installed ubuntu 16.04 , everything is ok but my bootup time is too long instead of my friend's ubuntu , so i ran `systend-analyze` and find the kernel load time is too much more others : 
    `Startup finished in 12.541s (kernel) + 8.443s (userspace) = 20.984s` 
I also attach plot  [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtrB.jpg)
is the load time normal for ubutnu on a ssd ? 
thanks to your respons .

```
 mostafa@N55: ~ $ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 109.5G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  35.4G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0  93.1G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb2   8:18   0  47.7G  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0 643.3G  0 part
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel load time isn't that much affected by using a SSD. It's a small file that gets decompressed to RAM and then runs from there. What is probably taking time is hardware initialization, not I/O.

Check `dmesg` messages and see if you can find any hardware that is taking that long to init, 12 seconds is indeed slow for current hardware. What is your CPU?

The plot is useless, as it only lists userspace, and your userspace boot time looks good.

Comment: I have asus n55sf (8G ram , i7) , I checked dmesg but I can understand any thing except a line that load usb takes long time to load i think . ` usb 2-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci` @Daniel

Comment: my dmesg output as a text file [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hFkSYJcpF7QlVsd1RUSng2NEU/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: I find that `new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci` takes about 7s to load !! what can i do ???

Comment: Try booting without the device, just disconnect it and check if it makes any difference.